# Conversion of IF SQL from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I'm converting a PHP script as DB has been switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

I know PG doesn't have the IF function but does have the CASE function. What is the best way to convert this MySQL statement?

```
  SELECT albums.id, 
         albums.albumname, 
         sum(if(((albums.id=allalbums.albumid) and 
             (allalbums.photoid=$photoid)),1,0)) as inalbum 
    FROM albums, allalbums 
GROUP BY albums.id 
ORDER BY albums.createdate desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select 
  albums.id, 
  albums.albumname, 
  sum(
   case when ((albums.id=allalbums.albumid) and (allalbums.photoid=$photoid)) then 1
     else 0
   end
  ) as inalbum 
from albums,allalbums 
group by albums.id 
order by albums.createdate desc
```

Comment: @Simon:  Good solution.  I believe PostgreSQL requires all non-aggregate columns to be specified in the GROUP BY clause; whereas MySQL I believe does not (!?).

Comment: IF is not part of the SQL standards, that's why PostgreSQL doesn't have IF. The complete GROUP BY is also SQL standard, that's why you have to use a complete GROUP BY. Same in other databases, MySQL is the exception.